# C Programming fork() multiple pipe()

Tags: c, unix, fork, pipe

Im simulating a shell using pipes() forks() exec() dup().  Ive seen a few posts on stackoverflow to guide be along the way.  But my prog seems to have similar issues as others have encountered here.

I use a LinkedList struct contains: char* cmd and char** args (ex. cmd='ls' args = '-l -d')

Here are some output results:
    ls -l 
    ls -l -a (as many args I want)
    ls -l | sort

```
ls -l | wc -w (runs but spits out wrong value)
ls | wc -w (runs, but spits out the wrong value)
ls (alone - no args, spits out A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.)
ls -l | sort | wc -w (causes system to hang)
```

It now at least pretend like it is taking the multiple args but invalid results or system hanging.

```
void runCommand(Node* head)
{
    int old_fd[2], new_fd[2];
    int isValid, cpid, pid;

    //Loop through all commands
    for(int cmd = 0; cmd < cmdCount; cmd++)
    {
        //if(curr cmd has next cmd)
        if(cmd+1 < cmdCount)
        {
            //Create pipe new_fd
            if( pipe(new_fd) == -1) //pipe error
            {
            perror("Pipe Error.");
            exit(-1);
            }
        }

        //Parent
        if( (pid=fork()) != 0 ) //parent
        {
            //Wait for child process
            //wait(0); //moved below

            //Curr cmd has next command
            if(cmd+1 < cmdCount)
            {
                old_fd[0] = new_fd[0];
                old_fd[1] = new_fd[1];
            }

            //Curr cmd has previous command
            if(cmd-1 > -1)
            {
            close(old_fd[0]);
            close(old_fd[1]);
            }
        }
        //Child process
        else //if fork() == 0
        {
            //Curr cmd has previous command
            if(cmd-1 > -1)
            {
                dup2(old_fd[0], 0); // setting up old_pipe to input into the child
                close(old_fd[0]);
                close(old_fd[1]);
            }

            //Curr cmd has next command
            if(cmd+1 < cmdCount)
            {
                close(new_fd[0]); // setting up new_pipe to get output from child
                dup2(new_fd[1], 1);
                close(new_fd[1]);
            }

            printf("Running command '%s': \n",getCmd(cmd,head));
            printf("Arguments: "); printArgs(cmd,head);
            //Below works for 1 cmd 1+ args, but not 1 cmd 0 arg or mult pipes
            isValid = execvp(getCmd(cmd,head), getArgs(cmd,head));

            if(isValid == -1)
            printf("%s: Command not found.\n", getCmd(cmd,head));
        }
     wait();

    }
}
```

**Note this thread: [Another_Stack_Overflow_Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694706/problem-with-piping-commands-in-c) I used the example there and replaced my function with their "Working" sample.  Their working sample seems to work for most everything except a single command with no arguments like "ls" it simply just does nothing. and asks for input**

Here is the requested getCmd() and getArgs() functions, just calls "getNode()" which returns a Node* struct (containing char* and a char** and two ints) the getCmd extracts the char* cmd and the getArgs extracts the char** args.

```
char* getCmd(int index, Node* head)
{
  Node* curr = getNode(index,head);
  return curr->cmd;
}
char** getArgs(int index, Node* head)
{
  Node* curr = getNode(index,head);
  return curr->args;
}
```

Comment: The `wait(0);` is at the wrong place.

Comment: And what happens if fork fails? You are not handling this situation correctly.

Comment: Could you add your getCmd() and getArgs() functions?

Comment: @wildplasser: moved wait() see output results.......

Comment: @Kylo: posted the two functions, I should have had fork fail code in there but thought by looking at it someone might see where I went wrong.

Comment: 1) What does `getNode()` look like, how do you know that is does not return NULL? 2) why do you use the cmd[] array when you have the *head linked list available?

Comment: @wildplasser: getNode() points to head of linkedlist, then returns ptr based on given index to that node.  Each node has 1)char* command  2)char** args  3) int numArgs  4) int type - not in use right now  -- Also check out the link I updated my original post for another example someone else got working, in their own way.  When I use their function multiple pipes work, except for something like "ls" where there is only 1 command and 0 args.

Comment: But: why don't you just walk the linked list by chasing the ->next pointer? The nodes seem to have all the data present at the right place. (only the first node on the list will need some additional logic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1.
You should pass a NULL terminated array to **execvp()**:

```
execvp("ls", NULL); // invalid!!!
```

This should be:

```
const char *args[1] = { NULL };
execvp("ls", args);
```

2.
"Pipe operator" | is a shell extension so you cannot use it in **exec...** functions. You can specify only a single executable there.

Comment: In my parsing function (user inputs at terminal) it places the command in a malloc char*, and tokenizes the arguments into a malloc char**, i did malloc + 1 to the args char*** and set the last value to NULL, so these were already done.  The runCommand() uses execvp(char*,char** null terminated).

Comment: struct (containing char* and a char** and two ints) the getCmd extracts the char* cmd and the getArgs extracts the char** args.

Comment: OK. So the last one. Can I see how do you initialize your args in this structure? i.e. the way you put the arguments there.